# Stop when using libcurl on tuxedo after check certification

Tags: c, ssl, curl, libcurl

I’m trying to use libcurl to call Rest API.

My server env : Oracle tuxedo(pro *c), AIX 7.1

It does work using command “curl” on prompt.
I can also see the whole log by using verbose option.

But it keeps stopping when I tried to use it on client compiling with libcurl.

According to log.

It says…

- Trying 123.456.789.00:443…
- Connected to “api url”(123.456.789.00) port 443 (#0)
- ALPN, offering http/1.1
- Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
- successfully set certificate verify locations :
- CAfile: /var/ssl/cert.pem
- CApath: /var/ssl/certs/

And it stopped here!!!!

When I use curl command on prompt
It says exactly same,
But keeps going…

- TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
- TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
  …
  …
  Etc…

I have no idea what causes this
And what is the difference…

Can anybody give me some advice please?

Or is there any other way to call RestAPI easily on Pro *C or C?

========================================

All I did is using sample of libcurl.

```
static sample(){
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;

    curl = curl_easy_init();

    struct curl_slist *list = NULL;

    if(curl){
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://ApiUrl.here");
        list = curl_slist_append(list, "Content-Type: application/json");
        list = curl_slist_append(list, "ApiKey : realKey");

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, list);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERIFYPEER, 1L);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 1L);

        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        curl_slist_free_all(list);

        if(res != CURLE_OK){
            fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed : %s \n", curl_easy_strerror(res));
        }
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please quote the relevant lines from your program?

Comment: I just add my code. 
The differences are that I used “tx_printf” instead of “fprintf” to see a log on Oracle tuxedo client. 
And I put CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, CURLOPT_DEBUGFUNCTION and CURLOPT_VERBOSE. 
I did not use global init because of considering thread. But I tried it too.

Comment: Weird thing is that it is working when I use other “http” url. I have no idea what’s wrong while checking certifications or else. 
I did download cert via https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem
I also tried re-installing libcurl, curl, gcc, libgcc.

Comment: Add `--libcurl` to curl invocation to get equivalent C code and compare it with your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
list = curl_slist_append(list, "ApiKey : realKey");
```

I think that line is the issue.

[RFC7230 3.2.4. Field Parsing](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7230#section-3.2.4)

> No whitespace is allowed between the header field-name and colon.  In
> the past, differences in the handling of such whitespace have led to
> security vulnerabilities in request routing and response handling.  A
> server MUST reject any received request message that contains
> whitespace between a header field-name and colon with a response code
> of 400 (Bad Request).  A proxy MUST remove any such whitespace from a
> response message before forwarding the message downstream.

Remove the space:

```
list = curl_slist_append(list, "ApiKey: realKey");
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it doesn’t work. I also tried mock APi not using key. Btw, I tried to use “openssl” instead of “libcurl”. But there were syntax errors while compiling. I just put #include <openssl/ssl.h>. Then, it failed to compile. It says there’re syntax error in crypto.h and comp.h. Tried re-installing openssl and other version too but it didn’t work…