# Https request in c(pro*c) without openssl or libcurl

Tags: c, https, proc, oracle-pro-c, tuxedo

I have problems compiling with openssl in pro-c.

Also, libcurl suddenly stop after check verification.

So I’m looking for other way of https request.

Can anybody let me know an example of https request without using libcurl/openssl?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please take the [tour] and read about [ask] good questions. Lastly please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: And I think you should ask about the problem you actually have with your current code.

Comment: @Some programmer dude  
I already did. I lost that account so signed up new. These are the reasons why I’m  looking for other way. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69293312/stop-when-using-libcurl-on-tuxedo-after-check-certification
Also. This. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69388250/is-there-any-way-to-avoid-proc-precompiler

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using the Oracle database client library. I have experienced problems using OpenSSL libraries together with Oracle clients because they both export the same symbols (function names). During runtime, those functions are resolved dynamically, and calls from Oracle client end up calling OpenSSL and fail, or calls from libcurl end up in Oracle client and fail.
The solution that worked was to link with static libraries of OpenSSL and libcurl.